# TypeError: "x" is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, constructor

```
TypeError: Produto is not a constructor
    at exports.create (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\src\controllers\produtos.controller.js:18:4)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\TESTES\todoList\back-end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

"produtos constructor":

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const new_produto = new Produto(req.body);

    if(req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length ===0) {
        res.status(400).send({error: true, message: "Please provide all required field"});
    } else {
        Produto.create(new_produto, (err, Produto) => {
            if(err) res.send(err);

            res.json({
                error: false,
                message: "Produto added sucefull",
                data: Produto
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Produto`? Are you importing it somewhere?

Comment: const Produto = () => {
    this.id = produtos.id;
    this.nome = produtos.nome;
    this.tamanho = produtos.tamanho;
    this.preco = produtos.preco;
    this.quantidade = produtos.quantidade;
}

Produto.create = (newProd, result) => {
    dbConn.query("INSERT INTO produtos set ?", newProd, (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log(res.insertId);
            result(null, res.insertId);
        }
    });
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the definition of `Produto`.

From this

```
const Produto = () => { ... }
Produto.create = (newProd, result) => { ... }
```

to this

```
function Produto() { ... }
Produto.prototype.create = function (newProd, result) { ... }
```

This will create a constructor function along with a `create` method as opposed to an arrow function which does not create a constructor and is not the best for creating methods because it does not preserve the `this` context.